# flask-admin readonly collections

Tags: python, relationship, wtforms, flask-admin

I would like to set the collections on a few of our models to readonly. With a text field, this is easy:

```
form_widget_args = {
    'created': {
        'readonly': True
    }
}
```

However, when I pass the same thing for fields which are collections, the fields are not set to `readonly`.  This is true whether the collection originated on the model object or if it was the result of a `backref`.

Answer (score 1):

not enitely sure what your saying, but try using disabled

```
form_widget_args = {
'created': {
    'disabled': True
}
```

Comment: `disabled` does not provide the same behavior as `readonly`. I want to set fields which are collections (the result of `many` type relationships) to `readonly`.